# Gemara B'iyun - Teaching and Learning

Tags: talmud-gemara, product-recommendation, chinuch-education

I want to learn Gemara b'iyun in the same way that it is learned in the great Yeshivos.

Please can I have suggestions of source material that will take me forward in this.

Where can I get shiurim online that can take me through sugyas in a clear manner?

Comment: This is hard to answer without knowing you personally. People in yeshivos usually have years of gemara learning at the elementary and high school level first. The important thing is  to  find people to help you grow at your level. I would recommend something like Partners in Torah or finding a local shiur you like.

Comment: Perhaps a sefer like Toras Roshei Hayeshivos would be good for you. I don't know if they have it on all the mesechtos, but it's a compilation of the shiurim of many roshei yeshiva from the past century. Going through the pieces in there in depth may help you  train your mind to think along the derech of some of these rabbanim and yeshivos.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a folder that has shiurim from the Mir from a talmid of Rav Asher Arieli. These shiurim include the sources (mareh m'komos). The shiurim are all typed out, very clear, broken into digestible units.

B'iyun, in-depth Gemara is just too difficult to learn through audio or video. A good b'iyun shiur reveals the complexity, layers, and nuance of the Gemara. To try to grasp all of that through video or audio is very ineffective. But having it written out, although serves as no substitute for being in a shiur, is a good second choice. You can read and reread as fast or as slow as you like, search within the text, copy-past and make your own short-handed notes, etc.

It's an extremely advanced shiur but if you have some basic knowledge of Gemara you should be able to follow. But even if you have been through these sugyas before, it's worthwhile to learn the Mir Mehalech as well. From the profundity of the shiurim, you get a feel that the Gemara is Divine.

The folder is constantly being updated as the Mir goes through the cycle.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1u8wZw6PRxxlTANo2DXf410KNIbfdOEwj?usp=sharing

Comment: Who is this talmid

Comment: I didn't include the Rebbe's name because he might not want to be associated with my notes. But his shiur is phenomenal and my writeup is close to perfection in terms of what he actually said. I did my best to write a word-for-word transcription.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize the Rebbe himself didn't write these...that wasn't clear from what you wrote.